# using existing inputs to create form for user to sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

using User model, created by devise, and Simple Form gem i want to give user ability to log in from main page. i have inputs, created just for it in haml, and want to use them for this:

```
.login-wrapper
        .user-fields
          %input{type: "text", placeholder: "username", class: "ribbon-placeholder mail"}
          .slide
            %input{type: "password", placeholder: "password", class: "ribbon-placeholder password"}
            = link_to "#", class: "ribbon-button" do
              %span register
              .account-arrow
          .clearfix

        %input{type: "submit", value: "log in", class: "ribbon-button orange-background log-in"}
```

Comment: You can do it but where is a form tag?

Comment: thats exactly my point;]

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can use the form like this. This is just for reference is not exactly form like yours:-

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div>
        <label class="checkbox" for="merchant_remember_me">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember Me
        </label>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
<br />
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: isnt it just a devise standard view?

Comment: Yes, you just have to override it